# How do you create an increment of 1 in the Label Blade Template?

Tags: laravel

From the template of the blade a tag td foreach the I want to increase by one. How can I do that?

```php
@foreach($winners as $winner)
    <tr>
        <td scope="row">
            <span class="badge">1</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width:300px">
            {{ $winner->name }}
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="width:50px">
            {{ $winner->point }}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: if you are using pagination its not good. because if you are swithing to some other pages the serail number will start again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use php tags, apologies for formatting written on mobile

```
@php $i = 0; @endphp
@foreach($winners as $winner)
 <tr>
    <td scope="row">
        <span class="badge">{{ $i }} </span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:300px">
        {{ $winner->name }} 
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="width:50px">
        {{ $winner->point }}
    </td>
 </tr>
 @php $i ++;  @endphp
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Didn't downvote it, and already removed the comment; thanks for fixing. Downvote is likely cause you didn't show how to use `$i` in context of the code that's there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice updated answer to clear up useage

Answer (score 7):

Laravel's `@foreach` automatically has a variable called `$loop`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable

You can simply do:
`<td scope="row"><span class="badge">{{ $loop->iteration }}</span></td>`

Comment: This is the cleanest solution and should be the accepted answer, because it uses readily available Blade functionality rather than manually creating/updating an index. This use case is exactly why Laravel makes available that `$loop` variable.

Comment: yea. however, sometimes you need to hard code to achieve a optimal result.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@php
  $i=1;
  @endphp

@foreach($winners as $winner)
    <tr>
        <td scope="row">
            <span class="badge">{{ $i++ }}</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width:300px">
            {{ $winner->name }}
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="width:50px">
            {{ $winner->point }}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```